# SegFault while using Malloc/Realloc on an uninitialized pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I'm working on a "light drone simulator" (in C) and one of my task is to add a static target when I left click on the map. So far so good. 
The thing is that instead of creating a matrix with given sizes as a global variable I would like to start from an uninitialized pointer of pointer and as soon as I left click, I realloc new memory in order to always have enough memory available but not more. Also my "matrix" should have 4 columns for 3D coordinates and 1 for "activation".

Here is a part of my code:

```
/* Main program */

double **TargetsArray;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

/* Call of model-specific mouse handling function */
   HandleSpecialMouseEvent(button, state, x, y, &ActualFlockingParams,
            &ActualVizParams, TargetPosition, TargetsArray, Modder);
}
```

```
void HandleSpecialMouseEvent(int button,
        int state,
        int x,
        int y,
        flocking_model_params_t * FlockingParams,
        vizmode_params_t * VizParams, 
        double * CoordTarg, double ** TargetsArray,
        const int Modifier) {

       static int cnt = 0;

       if (button == GLUT_LEFT && state == GLUT_DOWN && Modifier == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT) {
            FillVect(CoordTarg, MouseCoordToReal_2D(x, VizParams->MapSizeXY,
                    VizParams->Resolution) + VizParams->CenterX, -MouseCoordToReal_2D(y, VizParams->MapSizeXY,
                    VizParams->Resolution) + VizParams->CenterY, 0);
            printf("%d\n", cnt);

            if (cnt == 0) {

                TargetsArray = malloc( sizeof *TargetsArray );
                TargetsArray[cnt] = malloc( sizeof **TargetsArray * 4);
                printf("Hello");
                TargetsArray[cnt][0] = CoordTarg[0];
                TargetsArray[cnt][1] = CoordTarg[1];
                TargetsArray[cnt][2] = 0;
                TargetsArray[cnt][3] = 1;

                cnt += 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("Youhou");
                TargetsArray = realloc(TargetsArray, sizeof *TargetsArray * (cnt + 1) );
                TargetsArray[cnt] = malloc( sizeof **TargetsArray * 4);
                TargetsArray[cnt][0] = CoordTarg[0];
                TargetsArray[cnt][1] = CoordTarg[1];
                TargetsArray[cnt][2] = 0;
                TargetsArray[cnt][3] = 1;
                TargetsArray[cnt - 1][3] = 0;

                cnt += 1;

            }

            // for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
            //     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //         printf("%f\t", TargetsArray[j][i]);
            //     }
            //     printf("\n");
            // }
        }


}
```

I usually get 2 types of errors:

```
0
Hello1
Youhou2
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)

OR 

0
Hello1
free(): invalid next size (fast)
Abandon (core dumped)
```

I know there are simplier ways of doing it but I'd really like to understand why this is not working. I'm pretty sure it is due to the way I use *malloc* and *realloc* but I also don't understand why in the first "loop" the program doesn't go into the if statement whereas it does print "0" and then why it prints "Hello" before printing the counter (cnt) ?

I hope I put enough code for you to understand my issue but please let me know if something is missing.

Thanks !!

Comment: The title says "using Malloc/Realloc on an uninitialized pointer". Why not init it? Initialising variables (all, but especially those which are potentially or guaranteed to be used before first write) is generally a good idea.

Comment: `realloc` *will not work* with an uninitialised pointer. Set it to `NULL`.

Comment: @Yunnosch my goal was to initialize it as soon as I first use my "left-click" function because I might not need it at all.

Comment: And how can you tell that is had not been used before? By initialising it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I use `realloc` only after using `malloc` a first time so it should be initialized

Comment: The value of `TargetsArray` is thrown away every time you leave the function. It is a function argument, and the allocated pointer is not a value returned by the function.

Comment: How do you reckon that? The function argument `double ** TargetsArray` is overwritten by `TargetsArray = malloc( sizeof *TargetsArray );`

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you the value is thrown away but as `TargetsArray` is a global variable the address of the pointer shouldn't change even when entering or exiting the function or myabe this it where I'm wrong ? The `malloc` command is used just once for initialization then I would like to use `realloc` to "add a line" to my `TargetsArray` but I assume my pointer of pointer is already of "shape" 1x4.

Comment: The local variable `TargetsArray` (a function argument) "shadows" the global variable `TargetsArray` and they are *different* variables. A deleted comment mentioned this, and the argument should be removed (but better not to use a global variable).

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok I get it, Does that mean that it is not possible (not recommended)  to modify the memory allocated for a global variable within a function itself imported from a different file and thus doesn't have directly access to the global variable (I hope I'm clear...) 
Also I made it work by allocating enough space directly in the main function and then writing values in the `HandleSpecialMouseEvent` function but the goal was really to allocate the exact amount of memory needed which is no longer the case now. Thanks for your time btw

Comment: You could have made `TargetsArray` a `static` variable inside the function, and returned that value instead of having a `void` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your function's argument `TargetsArray` so that it points on the global variable and not only store the same value.

Main program:

```c
double **TargetsArray;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

/* Call of model-specific mouse handling function */
   HandleSpecialMouseEvent(button, state, x, y, &ActualFlockingParams,
            &ActualVizParams, TargetPosition, &TargetsArray, Modder);
}
```

```c
void HandleSpecialMouseEvent(int button,
        int state,
        int x,
        int y,
        flocking_model_params_t * FlockingParams,
        vizmode_params_t * VizParams, 
        double * CoordTarg, double *** TargetsArray,
        const int Modifier) {

       static int cnt = 0;

       if (button == GLUT_LEFT && state == GLUT_DOWN && Modifier == GLUT_ACTIVE_ALT) {
            FillVect(CoordTarg, MouseCoordToReal_2D(x, VizParams->MapSizeXY,
                    VizParams->Resolution) + VizParams->CenterX, -MouseCoordToReal_2D(y, VizParams->MapSizeXY,
                    VizParams->Resolution) + VizParams->CenterY, 0);
            printf("%d\n", cnt);

            if (cnt == 0) {

                *TargetsArray = malloc( sizeof **TargetsArray );
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt] = malloc( sizeof ***TargetsArray * 4);
                printf("Hello\n");
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][0] = CoordTarg[0];
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][1] = CoordTarg[1];
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][2] = 0;
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][3] = 1;

                cnt += 1;
            }
            else {
                printf("Youhou");
                *TargetsArray = realloc(*TargetsArray, sizeof **TargetsArray * (cnt + 1) );
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt] = malloc( sizeof ***TargetsArray * 4);
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][0] = CoordTarg[0];
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][1] = CoordTarg[1];
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][2] = 0;
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt][3] = 1;
                (*TargetsArray)[cnt - 1][3] = 0;

                cnt += 1;

            }

            // for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
            //     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //         printf("%f\t", *TargetsArray[j][i]);
            //     }
            //     printf("\n");
            // }
        }


}
```

NOTE: Parentheses are very important

In each time you reallocate memory, you are storing a new memory address in your `TargetsArray`. Since you're changing the value inside the function, you need to give your function the address of the variable `TargetsArray`. Other ways you will only store the reallocated address on the function's local `TargetsArray`.

Answer (score 0):

The lines about malloc, and realloc, please check the memory you asked is available and could be allocated, both return a `NULL` in case of error.

Simply check if there are enough memory, and could be allocated, for both alloc calls, like following:

```c
TargetsArray = malloc( sizeof *TargetsArray );
if(TargetsArray  == NULL){
//oh! not enough mem, or whatever...
}
//...
void* TargetsArray_ra = realloc(TargetsArray, sizeof(*TargetsArray) * (cnt + 1) );
if(TargetsArray_ra == NULL){
//oh! could not realloc
//if you wish to return, don't forget to free up the TargetsArray 
if(TargetsArray != NULL){free(TargetsArray);TargetsArray=NULL;}
//return;
}else{//when realloc was success
TargetsArray = TargetsArray_ra ;
}
```

Same check for `TargetsArray[cnt] = malloc( sizeof **TargetsArray * 4);`, make sure it takes a proper non-`NULL` ptr, before you access it

Also those if-else blocks are kind of the same, except the last statement, besides that when you debug the code, at which line you get segfault?
You sure the passed `CoordTarg` is not `NULL`, and has proper length?
What about `FillVect` func? it's working as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I get the segfault for the realloc, the first malloc is passed but I'm not even sure if it is taken into account.
The `CoordTarg` is not empty or `NULL` and the `FillVect` is working fine so I know that the problem is due to this malloc/realloc. 
Also my goal is to fill this global `TargetsArray` in the main to keep track of the previously used positions

Comment: Is this a embed app? what's your env? Use the sample code i provided, check what does `realloc` returns? Use a debugger to findout the exact line causes a segfault

Comment: It's not an embed app, I'm on Linux Visual Studio and using C and OpenGL. This part is actually part of the OpenGL loop. I tried your code but still have the same issue as if the program was trying to free some memory. The weird thing is that error often happens when I move my mouse too much on the simulator. When I backtrace my error on the debugger it is mainly internal Linux programs that are raised.

Comment: Another possibilities is about freeing up a pointer that already-freed. So maybe somewhere else the `TargetsArray` gets free, and it's about gets free again.
Search for any possible `free(TargetsArray)` call, and always set any freed ptr to `NULL`, to avoid double-free something.
Also mind, I think as you stated the fast-move, so I smell some race-condition here, probably each mouse event is run parallel?! if yes, make sure any mem free-alloc is done thread-safe(using a mutex)